# How to remove count values "0" from result table?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query that returns a table with columns `name` and `numberOfClasses`. This table includes the name of all students and the amount of classes the student follows. I use the following database tables:

```
╔══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ TakesClasses ║           ║          ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ id           ║ person_id ║ class_id ║
║ 99           ║ 1         ║ 40       ║
║ 98           ║ 1         ║ 41       ║
║ 97           ║ 1         ║ 42       ║
║ 96           ║ 1         ║ 43       ║
║ 95           ║ 2         ║ 44       ║
║ 94           ║ 2         ║ 45       ║
║ 93           ║ 2         ║ 46       ║
╚══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
╔═════════╦═══════╦══╗
║ Persons ║       ║  ║
╠═════════╬═══════╬══╣
║ id      ║ name  ║  ║
║ 1       ║ Bart  ║  ║
║ 2       ║ David ║  ║
║ 3       ║ Dani  ║  ║
║ 4       ║ Erik  ║  ║
╚═════════╩═══════╩══╝
```

I used the following query:

```
SELECT
    name,
    COUNT(T.person_id) AS numberOfClasses 
FROM
    Persons P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TakesClasses T ON P.id = T.person_id
GROUP BY
    P.id, P.name
```

And this is the output:

```
╔═══════╦═════════════════╗
║ name  ║ numberOfClasses ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ Bart  ║           4     ║
║ Dani  ║           3     ║
║ David ║           0     ║
║ Erik  ║           0     ║
╚═══════╩═════════════════╝
```

How can I remove the entries with 0 from my the results table?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Do INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

```
select name, count(T.person_id) as amountOfClasses 
from Persons P join
     TakesClasses T
     on P.id = T.person_id
group by P.id, P.name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter on aggregated data like what comes out of `GROUP BY` you can use the `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT name,COUNT(T.person_id) as amountOfClasses 
       FROM Persons P LEFT OUTER JOIN TakesClasses T
       on P.id = T.person_id 
GROUP BY P.id, P.name
HAVING COUNT(T.person_id) > 0;
```

sqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1108c5/8